# Determine Which Route Was Resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Given routes like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
    <Route path="foo/:token" element={<Foo />} />
    <Route path=":token" element={<Bar />}>
      <Route path=":id" element={<Baz />}>
    <Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

How can `MainLayout` know which route was resolved? I need to know if it was within the route tree with `path=":token"`.

`useMatch('/:token/*')` does not work because it matches on path `foo/123`, which resolves to the `path="foo/:token"` route.

I can't figure out what `useResolvedPath` does or how I could use it. I just seems to echo the input param.

I can't use `const { token } = useParams()` since both routes have a param named `token`.

Ideas?

Comment: `MainLayout` contains global nav that should render differently based on the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about this wrong, and my question did not explain the context well enough to spot it.

`MainLayout` contains global nav elements that I want to be slightly different for different routes. Rather than have `MainLayout` look outward at the route, the router setup should tell `MainLayout` what to do. Like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
    <Route path="foo/:token" element={<Foo />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<MainLayout someParam={paramValue} />}>
    <Route path=":token" element={<Bar />}>
      <Route path=":id" element={<Baz />}>
    <Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Where `MainLayout` uses `paramValue` to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue, or question, is really about how to differentiate between the two routes that defined ***identical*** path parameter variables. In other words, you are trying to check which route the `token` path param was populated from.

My suggestion here would be to use ***different*** path parameter variable names to disambiguate them.

For example `fooToken` and `barToken`:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
    <Route path="foo/:fooToken" element={<Foo />} />
    <Route path=":barToken" element={<Bar />}>
      <Route path=":id" element={<Baz />}>
    <Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The `MainLayout` component can check for both and conditionally apply logic.

```js
const { barToken, fooToken } = useParams();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (barToken) {
    // bar token logic
  }

  if (fooToken) {
    // foo token logic
  }

}, [barToken, fooToken]);
...
```

An alternative would be to use the [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) hook and explicitly check for a match for each route that has a `token` path parameter.

```js
const MainLayout = () => {
  const fooMatch = useMatch("/foo/:token"); // foo token
  const barMatch = useMatch("/:token");     // bar token
  const bazMatch = useMatch("/:token/:id"); // bar token

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ fooMatch, barMatch, bazMatch });

    if (barMatch || bazMatch) {
      // bar token logic
    }

    if (fooMatch) {
      // foo token logic
    }

  }, [fooMatch, barMatch, bazMatch]);

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. I'll probably use the first option, even though it creates coupling between routes and also the `MainLayout.` I actually don't have multiple routes with `token` param as of now, but someone could later add a route that causes a name collision. The latter option is worse because it causes me to essentially duplicate route selection logic.

Comment: @TimScott Totally, I would only go the second method route as a last resort as it's a little unwieldy as the number of routes grow.